# Encoding Not supported Execption while parsing HL7 message

Tags: c#-4.0, hl7, hl7-v2

I have a  C#.NET application in which i am trying to construct an HL7 message and then send to other Application using NHAPI .The message is successfully constructed but it when i am trying to extract throws an error :**Encoding NotsupportedException**

Specifications:
.NET framework- 4
HL7 version-2.5

Language:C#

here is the piece of code

```
PipeParser ParserADT = new PipeParser();
                IMessage ParsedADTmsg = ParserADT.Parse(ADTMsg);
                string Msgstr = ParsedADTmsg.GetStructureName();
```

I get the exception immediately after the line above.

The constructed message:

```
MSH|^~\&|HIS|HIS1|||201405291223||ADT^A01^ADT_A01|73944|P|2.5 
EVN||201405291223 
PID|||102||Oberoi^Anjali^^^Ms||20140529|Female|||||^^PH|^^CP    
NK1|1234||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||^^CP 
PV1||Emergency –
```

Comment: How does your message look like? Show your message! By the way should it really be **ParserADT.Parse(ADTMsg)** instead of **ParserADT.parse(ADTMsg)**

Comment: MSH|^~\&|HIS|HIS1|||201405291223||ADT^A01^ADT_A01|73944|P|2.5
EVN||201405291223
PID|||102||Oberoi^Anjali^^^Ms||20140529|Female|||||^^PH|^^CP
NK1|1234||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||^^CP
PV1||Emergency

Comment: This is the ADT message which i am unable to parse

Answer (score 0):

Replace the space before EVN, NK1, and PV1 with a new line character, so that your message looks like this:

```
MSH|^~\&|HIS|HIS1|||201405291223||ADT^A01^ADT_A01|73944|P|2.5
EVN||201405291223 PID|||102||Oberoi^Anjali^^^Ms||20140529|Female|||||^^PH|^^CP
NK1|1234||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||^^CP
PV1||Emergency
```